# beep not working since upgrade to 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: sound, udev, evdev

I've just finished upgrading to Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS, and so far, only one issue has come up: When run as user, the `beep` command returns

> beep: Error: Could not open any device`.

Running `sudo beep` does not work, as expected. After a little bit of research, I have found that no `beep` group is existent on the system, as expected by the man page. I have tried reinstalling and reconfiguring without success.

To make things even stranger, `beep` works during boot via `rc.local`; at some point, however, it stops working and returns the error, thus breaking my `rc.local`-routine. Also, this command works just fine:

```
sudo env -u SUDO_GID -u SUDO_COMMAND -u SUDO_USER -u SUDO_UID beep
```

For clarification: I am running a headless home server that is not connected to any speakers; the simple noise-making-speaker is used for simple feedback during boot and if errors occur that require intervention. My setup used to work fine under Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS.

Comment: I don't know anything about `beep`, but the package description mentions `printf "\a"` ... so wondering if that works?

Comment: I get this error: `beep: Error: Set up permissions for the pcspkr evdev device file and run as non-root user instead.`

Comment: is pcspkr blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Comment: @nobody: pcspkr is not blacklisted. `beep` does work during startup and via the command added above, so it's not a driver issue.
@xiota: I guess it is a permissions issue, but I have now idea how to solve it…

Comment: Is your user in group audio server means no pulse audio I think.

Comment: alternative https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1974/how-do-i-make-my-pc-speaker-beep


 paplay /usr/share/sounds/sound-icons/capital

Answer (score 4):

Adding my user to group `input` worked for me, ie:

```
sudo usermod -aG input $USER
```

The change isn't visible until you log in again (On Ubuntu, I had to restart, not just log out and back in, before a new shell would display the new group in the output of `groups`.) To see the change within one shell, open a new login shell:

```
su $USER -
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. After a restart, and confirming I'm in the new group with `groups`, `beep` still outputs "Error: Could not open any device". Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: Seems to work for me and I don't even need to reboot or login again.

Answer (score 2):

One solution suggested in the doc [PERMISSIONS.md](https://github.com/spkr-beep/beep/blob/master/PERMISSIONS.md) is to create a system group called 'beep' and then use ACLs to allow members of that group write access to the device.

```
$ addgroup --system beep
```

Then create a rule for udev, e.g.

/lib/udev/rules.d/90-pcspkr-beep.rules :

```
# Add write access to the PC speaker for the "beep" group
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="PC Speaker", ENV{DEVNAME}!="", RUN+="/usr/bin/setfacl -m g:beep:w '$env{DEVNAME}'"
```

Then you should be able to add users to this group and they can write to the speaker:

```
$ usermod user_name -a -G beep
```

Of course the above will only work if you have ACLs turned on.  If you can't or won't do that, they have a different suggestion for the udev rule:

```
# Give write access to the PC speaker only to the "beep" group
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{name}=="PC Speaker", ENV{DEVNAME}!="", GROUP="beep", MODE="0620"
```

But this will remove the speaker from being written to by the default system group 'input'--adverse effects are probably negligible since this method is suggested in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

**Bad solution:**

I'm pretty sure this is a permissions issue, but I am not sure how to solve it. I tried creating `udev` files and groups according to the [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PC_speaker#Run_as_non-root_user), but that wouldn't work.

Then, I changed permissions on the device itself:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr
```

While this does work, it's surely a bad idea to make devices just writeable for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Making `beep` work has been a pain for several years. I ended up with this line of code, either as an alias in `~/.bash_aliases` or in a script named... well, `beep`.

```
/usr/bin/aplay /usr/share/sounds/sound-icons/prompt.wav 2>/dev/null &
```

Feel free to choose your command-line player and sound.